# knitr xtable highlight and add horizontal lines for the same row,

Tags: r, knitr, xtable, longtable

I am using knitr and xtable to automate my reporting procedure. I want to highlight a few rows of a table and have a horizontal line right above each row highlighted. The .Rnw file I am using reads as below:

```
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

<<do_table, results = "asis">>=
library(xtable)
mydf <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var1 = rnorm(10), var2 = runif(10))

print(xtable(mydf), add.to.row = list(pos = list(0,2), command = rep("\\rowcolor[gray]{0.75}",2)),hline.after=c(0,2))
@

\end{document}
```

This works just fine, however, the table I am working with should be a longtable, if I adjust the last line of code to

```
print(xtable(mydf), add.to.row = list(pos = list(0,2), command = rep("\\rowcolor[gray]{0.75}",2)),hline.after=c(0,2),tabular.environment="longtable",floating=FALSE)
```

the output is quite ugly, and the rows are not highlighted as expected. Anyone might know an answer to this question?

thanks,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but I am a bit confused: do you want the selected rows highlighted by `hline` *and* `rowcolor`? In my experience, rowcolor alone looks better,  so I will assume that in my answer below (but you could easily use both, just append the `\\hline` command).

As a bonus, all code below assumes you use the LaTeX `booktabs` package, which gives correctly weighted rules (unlike hline). To be honest, I always work with booktabs, and I couldn't bother to adjust the code to use hline -- but if you prefer hline, replace all `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` macros with `\hline`.

You seem to have missed that LaTeX longtables require a special header, and we need to supply that too as an element to the `command` vector of the `add.to.row` list (this may be the reason your typeset table looks bad).

```
longtable.xheader <-
   paste("\\caption{Set your table caption.}",
     "\\label{tab:setyourlabel}\\\\ ",
     "\\toprule ",
     attr(xtable(mydf), "names")[1],
     paste(" &", attr(xtable(mydf), "names")[2:length(attr(xtable(mydf), "names"))], collapse = ""),
     "\\\\\\midrule ",
     "\\endfirsthead ",
     paste0("\\multicolumn{", ncol(xtable(mydf)), "}{c}{{\\tablename\\ \\thetable{} -- continued from previous page}}\\\\ "),
     "\\toprule ",
     attr(xtable(mydf), "names")[1],
     paste("&", attr(xtable(mydf), "names")[2:length(attr(xtable(mydf), "names"))], collapse = ""),
     "\\\\\\midrule ",
     "\\endhead ",
     "\\midrule ",
     paste0("\\multicolumn{", as.character(ncol(xtable(mydf))), "}{r}{{Continued on next page}}\\\\ "),
     "\\bottomrule \\endfoot ",
     "\\bottomrule \\endlastfoot ",
     collapse = "")
```

With that taken care of, go ahead and `print` the xtable:

```
print(xtable(mydf), 
      floating = FALSE, % since longtable never floats
      hline.after = NULL, % hline off since I use booktabs
      add.to.row = list(pos = list(-1, 
                               c(0, 2),
                               nrow(xtable(mydf))),
                    command = c(longtable.xheader, 
                                "\\rowcolor[gray]{0.75}\n",
                                "%")), % comments out a spurious \hline by xtable
      include.rownames = FALSE, % depends on your preference
      include.colnames = FALSE, % depends on your preference
      type = "latex", 
      tabular.environment = "longtable",
      % xtable tries to escape TeX special chars, can be annoying sometimes
      sanitize.text.function = function(x){x},
      % not all dashes are meant to be math negative sign, set according to your data
      math.style.negative = FALSE)
```

I hope my use of booktabs in the answer did not confuse you too much.
Keep knitting!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, slightly offtopic, but demonstrating a markdown-only solution for highlighting cells/rows easily:

```
> mydf <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var1 = rnorm(10), var2 = runif(10))
> library(pander)
> emphasize.strong.rows(c(1, 3))
> pander(mydf)

---------------------------
 id      var1       var2   
----- ---------- ----------
**1** **0.7194** **0.6199**

  2     0.8094     0.1392  

**3** **-1.254** **0.5308**

  4     0.4505     0.8235  

  5    -0.3779     0.7534  

  6    -0.3518     0.3055  

  7     1.759      0.5366  

  8     0.9822     0.9938  

  9     1.549      0.3589  

 10     -1.077     0.5153  
---------------------------
```

That can be converted to LaTeX or pdf directly.

Answer (score 1):

You might have more luck posting this on a latex forum. You should note that xcolor/longtable are not compatible: http://www.ukern.de/tex/xcolor.html.